# Problem with saving multiple records in JSON file to MySQL using django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm newbie in django I'm trying to save JSON record using Dango-rest-framework, here is my JSON file.

```
{
   "result":{
      "lists":[
         {
            "resAccountBalance":"0",
            "resWithdrawalAmt":"0",
            "commStartDate":"20190124",
            "commEndDate":"20190724",
            "resTrHistoryList":[
               {
                  "resAccountTrDate":"20190723",
                  "resAccountTrTime":"070609",
                  "resAccountOut":"132795",
                  "resAccountIn":"0",
                  "resAccountDesc1":"",
                  "resAccountDesc2":"BC",
                  "resAccountDesc3":"카드출금",
                  "resAccountDesc4":"",
                  "resAfterTranBalance":"0"
               },
               {
                  "resAccountTrDate":"20190722",
                  "resAccountTrTime":"071125",
                  "resAccountOut":"0",
                  "resAccountIn":"17",
                  "resAccountDesc1":"",
                  "resAccountDesc2":"이자",
                  "resAccountDesc3":"2019년결산",
                  "resAccountDesc4":"",
                  "resAfterTranBalance":"132795"
               },
               {
                  "resAccountTrDate":"20190515",
                  "resAccountTrTime":"031314",
                  "resAccountOut":"0",
                  "resAccountIn":"180000",
                  "resAccountDesc1":"",
                  "resAccountDesc2":"타행이체",
                  "resAccountDesc3":"지원금",
                  "resAccountDesc4":"",
                  "resAfterTranBalance":"626109"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to save 3 records in `resTrHistoryList` to MySQL, but only the following is saved:

```
record({
   "resAccountTrDate":"20190515",
   "resAccountTrTime":"031314",
   "resAccountOut":"0",
   "resAccountIn":"180000",
   "resAccountDesc1":"",
   "resAccountDesc2":"타행이체",
   "resAccountDesc3":"지원금",
   "resAccountDesc4":"",
   "resAfterTranBalance":"626109"
})
```

Here is my code.

model.py

```py
class QuickQuiryBankKDB(models.Model): 
    result = models.TextField()
    resAccountTrDate = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    resAccountTrDate = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    resAccountTrTime = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    resAccountOut = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    resAccountIn = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    resAccountDesc1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    resAccountDesc2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    resAccountDesc3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    resAccountDesc4 = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    resAfterTranBalance = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1000')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __str__ on Python 3
        return self.QuickQuiryBankKDB
```

serializers.py

```py
class QuickQuiryBankKDBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        super(QuickQuiryBankKDBSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = QuickQuiryBankKDB
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['result']
```

views.py

```py
class QuickQuiryBankKDBViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QuickQuiryBankKDB.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuickQuiryBankKDBSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer_class):
        if (serializer_class.validated_data['result'][2:8] == 'result'):
            json_text = serializer_class.validated_data['result']
            json_unpacked = json.loads(json_text)

            for i in json_unpacked['result']['lists'][0]['resTrHistoryList']:

                resAccountTrDate = i['resAccountTrDate']
                resAccountTrTime = i['resAccountTrTime']
                resAccountOut = i['resAccountOut']
                resAccountIn = i['resAccountIn']
                resAccountDesc1 = i['resAccountDesc1']
                resAccountDesc2 = i['resAccountDesc2']
                resAccountDesc3 = i['resAccountDesc3']
                resAccountDesc4 = i['resAccountDesc4']
                resAfterTranBalance = i['resAfterTranBalance']
                serializer_class.save(resAccountTrDate=resAccountTrDate, resAccountTrTime=resAccountTrTime, resAccountOut=resAccountOut, resAccountIn=resAccountIn,
                                  resAccountDesc1=resAccountDesc1, resAccountDesc2=resAccountDesc2, resAccountDesc3=resAccountDesc3, resAccountDesc4=resAccountDesc4,
                                  resAfterTranBalance=resAfterTranBalance)
```

Hope to have a hint to solve the problem. Thank you!

Based on tips from @cagrias, I revised **views.py** as follow.

```py
class QuickQuiryBankKDBViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QuickQuiryBankKDB.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuickQuiryBankKDBSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer_class):
        serializer_class = QuickQuiryBankKDBSerializer(data=self.request.data, many=True)
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            if (serializer_class.validated_data['result'][2:8] == 'result'):
                json_text = serializer_class.validated_data['result']
                json_unpacked = json.loads(json_text)

                for i in json_unpacked['result']['lists'][0]['resTrHistoryList']:

                    resAccountTrDate = i['resAccountTrDate']
                    resAccountTrTime = i['resAccountTrTime']
                    resAccountOut = i['resAccountOut']
                    resAccountIn = i['resAccountIn']
                    resAccountDesc1 = i['resAccountDesc1']
                    resAccountDesc2 = i['resAccountDesc2']
                    resAccountDesc3 = i['resAccountDesc3']
                    resAccountDesc4 = i['resAccountDesc4']
                    resAfterTranBalance = i['resAfterTranBalance']
                    print('1')
                    serializer_class.save(resAccountTrDate=resAccountTrDate, resAccountTrTime=resAccountTrTime, resAccountOut=resAccountOut, resAccountIn=resAccountIn,
                                      resAccountDesc1=resAccountDesc1, resAccountDesc2=resAccountDesc2, resAccountDesc3=resAccountDesc3, resAccountDesc4=resAccountDesc4,
                                      resAfterTranBalance=resAfterTranBalance)
```

but **serializer_class.validated_data** gives nothing but blank list [], while **self.request.data** gives full records of data what I want. Do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to save multiple objects in one request you need to init your serializer with `many=True` command. You are extending `ModelViewSet` class in your view and `create` method is the place where your serializers are initiated. So you need to edit your `views.py` such as:

```py
class QuickQuiryBankKDBViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QuickQuiryBankKDB.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuickQuiryBankKDBSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)

        if (request.data['result'][2:8] == 'result'):
            json_text = request.data['result']
            json_unpacked = json.loads(json_text)

            for i in json_unpacked['result']['lists'][0]['resTrHistoryList']:

                resAccountTrDate = i['resAccountTrDate']
                resAccountTrTime = i['resAccountTrTime']
                resAccountOut = i['resAccountOut']
                resAccountIn = i['resAccountIn']
                resAccountDesc1 = i['resAccountDesc1']
                resAccountDesc2 = i['resAccountDesc2']
                resAccountDesc3 = i['resAccountDesc3']
                resAccountDesc4 = i['resAccountDesc4']
                resAfterTranBalance = i['resAfterTranBalance']

                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                self.perform_create(serializer, resAccountTrDate=resAccountTrDate, resAccountTrTime=resAccountTrTime, resAccountOut=resAccountOut, resAccountIn=resAccountIn,
                                  resAccountDesc1=resAccountDesc1, resAccountDesc2=resAccountDesc2, resAccountDesc3=resAccountDesc3, resAccountDesc4=resAccountDesc4,
                                  resAfterTranBalance=resAfterTranBalance)
                headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
        else:
            return Response("error", status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer_class, **args):
        serializer.save(args)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice @cagrias. As your tips, I revised views.py as follows.     def perform_create(self, serializer_class):
        serializer_class = QuickQuiryBankKDBSerializer(data=self.request.data, many=True)
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            print(serializer_class.validated_data)
            if (serializer_class.validated_data['result'][2:8] == 'result'):
                json_text = serializer_class.validated_data['result']
                json_unpacked = json.loads(json_text)

Comment: Please add that in your question, its impossible to read from comment.

Comment: But "print(serializer_class.validated_data)" gives me blank list, while "print(self.request.data)" gives me full data what I want. Do you have any idea for this situation??

Comment: OK! plz your understand because it is my first question in stack. I'm not familiar with it. I try to

Comment: I run your code, I got error in "if (serializer_class.validated_data['result'][2:8] == 'result'):" because serializer_class.validated_data is blank []. I checked serializer_class.is_valid() which gives "True". Do you have any idea for it??

Comment: I've edited my answer. you need to pt your logic before validating your serializer

Comment: Thank you for your comment @cagrias, and I learned a lot from your comment. I got another error, "TypeError: save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". Print(arg) gives multiple arguments. I tried to override save method in various way, but failed. Can you give some advice for this problem...

Comment: Can you give all arguments to save explicitly? Such as serializer.save(resAccountTrDate=resAccountTrDate, ...) etc.

Comment: explicitly saving each arguments gives following error message, NotImplementedError: Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by default, only multiple create. For updates it is unclear how to deal with insertions and deletions. If you need to support multiple update, use a `ListSerializer` class and override `.update()` so you can specify the behavior exactly.

Comment: Following the error message, I tried to revise update method instead using .perform_create(), but failed...

Comment: Actually you can delete many=True and create one serializer per one for loop. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Oh! I understand! Thank you for your kind response. Finally, I got the result what I want.